# Multilevel Longitudinal Model - Convergence Issues

Tags: r, panel-data

I have repeated measures (collected at 3 time points) data that has a nested structure (6695 individuals within 5140 households).

I am interested in to what extent certain predictors (demographic, financial and care responsibilities) explain the varying trajectories of the DV (mental health score) over the three time points and how this differs between intersectional groups (BAME Men, BAME Women, White Women, White Men).

So far I am working on a piecewise multilevel linear growth model.

Code for this model including demographic predictors as follows:

```
lmer(GHQ~  Time1 + Time2 + Sex + BAME + AgeC + AgeCQuad + Sex*BAME + 
   (1 + Time1 + Time2 | pidp) + (0 + Time1 + Time2 | i_hidp) + 
   (1| i_hidp), data = ldata, REML = FALSE, 
  control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore", 
  optimizer ="Nelder_Mead"))
```

I was going to then stratify the data by intersectional group and run the same model on all, comparing between group intercepts using Chow tests.

Please could somebody advise if I am doing the right thing here? I'm currently getting convergence issues and wondering if a simpler model is possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why Nelder-Mead?  In my experience it's generally one of the worse choices. Have you read `?lme4::convergence` ?  Also, why fit a bunch of stratified models when you could do a simpler statistical comparison of the significance of the various `BAME+Sex+BAME:Sex` terms?

Comment: No reason for either other than inexperience, unfortunately. Thank you for the tips!